# How can I return a string instead of a number when the number is 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I have a formula that returns average lbs, waist and body fat % for the weeks I've been dieting. The problem is I didn't measure body fat % until a while after I started so some averages are 0. I'd prefer to display N/A instead of 0%, is this possible? And can this formula be made less convoluted? Body fat is in column D.

```
={query(query({ArrayFormula((if(len(Log!A2:A), quotient(Log!A2:A - min(Log!A2:A), 7) + 1, ))), Log!B2:B}, "select Col1, Avg(Col2) where Col1 > 0 group by Col1"), "select Col1"), ArrayFormula(round(query({ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), quotient(Log!A2:A - min(Log!A2:A), 7) + 1, )), Log!B2:B}, "select Avg(Col2) where Col1 > 0 group by Col1 label Avg(Col2) ''"), 1) & " lbs"), ArrayFormula(round(query({ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), quotient(Log!A2:A - min(Log!A2:A), 7) + 1, )), Log!C2:C}, "select Avg(Col2) where Col1 > 0 group by Col1 label Avg(Col2) ''"), 1) & " cm"), ArrayFormula(round(query({ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), quotient(Log!A2:A - min(Log!A2:A), 7) + 1, )), Log!D2:D}, "select Avg(Col2) where Col1 > 0 group by Col1 label Avg(Col2) ''"), 1) & "%")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- no need to have multiple **`ARRAYFORMULA`** functions in one formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 QUERY(QUERY({IF(LEN(Log!A2:A), QUOTIENT(Log!A2:A-MIN(Log!A2:A), 7)+1, ), Log!B2:B}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) where Col1>0 group by Col1"), "select Col1"), 
 ROUND(QUERY({IF(LEN(Log!A2:A), QUOTIENT(Log!A2:A-MIN(Log!A2:A), 7)+1, ), Log!B2:B}, 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col1>0 group by Col1 label avg(Col2)''"), 1)&" lbs", 
 ROUND(QUERY({IF(LEN(Log!A2:A), QUOTIENT(Log!A2:A-MIN(Log!A2:A), 7)+1, ), Log!C2:C}, 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col1>0 group by Col1 label avg(Col2)''"), 1)&" cm", 
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(
 ROUND(QUERY({IF(LEN(Log!A2:A), QUOTIENT(Log!A2:A-MIN(Log!A2:A), 7)+1, ), Log!D2:D}, 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col1>0 group by Col1 label avg(Col2)''"), 1)&"%"), 
 "^0%$", "N/A")})
```